# What does it mean, "fill someone with a terrible resolve"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This famous Japanese war quote is:

> [I fear all we have done is to awaken a sleeping giant and  **fill him
>   with a terrible resolve**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoroku_Yamamoto%27s_sleeping_giant_quote).

What does it mean, "fill someone with a terrible resolve"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the use of *resolve* as a noun that puzzles you?

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/resolve_2

The attack on Pearl Harbor made America determined to fight back.

Comment: Is it the use of resolve as a noun that puzzles you? - YES

Comment: "Terrible resolve" means that the Americans would be filled with a terrifying determination to win the war. It would be terrible for the Japanese.